# Performance issue with groovy script eval(string) method

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to track down the source of a performance problem with the groovy eval(string) method being called within a Java application.  If I execute the following code;

```
String pattern = "test = ['one','two','three']";
engine.eval(pattern)
```

it runs in virtually no time (0 to 1ms)

However, if I say the following

```
String first = "['one','two','three']";
String pattern = "test = " + first; // "identical" String to first approach 
engine.eval(pattern)
```

it takes ~30+ ms to run.

What's worse, after several thousand invocations it will be as high as 60 - 70ms although I'm far less concerned about this than the time delta between the two implementations.

Any explanations as to why this is happening / suggestions on how to avoid this?  I suspect it has something to do with the Java and/or Groovy compiler and I've started looking at the compile() method but I'd prefer it if there's a simple way to make the existing code work (less things to change that way).

Comment: Exactly, but the strings are equivalent by the time they're passed into eval() which is why I suspect it's a compiler or run-time optimization issue (apologies if that's what you're saying)...

Comment: How do you construct the engine? Are you using JSR-223? If so, take a look at http://groovy.codehaus.org/JSR+223+Scripting+with+Groovy and the last paragraph: `The engine keeps per default hard references to the script functions.` If you use a constant inlined String then groovy might optimize here. Whereas a concatenation can cause the expression to be treated as a new String and not a cached Script which may cause this difference you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-jsr223/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/jsr223/GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java?source=cc you will find a cache for mapping Strings to classes. The problem is that the ManagedConcurrentMap is basically an identity hashmap, meaning if you use the same string over and over again it will be fast, because compilation is skipped for subsequent runs. The problem version creates a new string every time, thus it needs to be compiled every time, causing a new class being generated every time as well.

On how to avoid this: create a hash based cache

Comment: Thanks very much blackdrag!  You have solved the mystery, quite likely several.  Since you're someone that appears to understand groovy internals quite well (I've read a number of your posts), doesn't it seem strange to you that they use the identity map rather than a standard map?  Having just learned this we're busy looking at our use of Groovy throughout the entire application - there are a number of places where we were expecting code to be cached because the effective strings are essentially the same. No wonder we were generating so many classes / using so much permgen. Thanks again!

Comment: Another question for you if you have a moment.  In light of this news, we're thinking about keeping our own lookup map to ensure that we always return the same String - any potential problems / concerns?  If not, I'll post an update on how things go for us...

Comment: sorry for the late answer... I see no problem with a custom lookup map, as long as you keep concurrency and memory in mind. Those two are not trivial though.

as for why an IdentityMap... frankly... I made this change and I am thinking I may have overlooked that part... Shame on me

Answer (score 0):

`eval`'s in any language are notoriously slow and often advised to stay away from ("eval is evil").  However, in your code it seems more that the string concatenation is causing the slowdown, rather than the eval itself.

Still, a few milliseconds shouldn't be cause for concern -- have you determined that this is causing a performance bottleneck in your code? Micromanaging the code may lead to bugs and unclear code in the future which may have much worse implications.

Comment: Sadly yes,it is something that can potentially be called thousands of times taking jobs from a few seconds to 5+ minutes.  What's worse, is the same job run a second time takes 10 mins (15-20 mins the next) due to the increasing run times of the eval that I mentioned.  We could live with the 5 minutes if we solved the second problem but it's not as simple as just compiling the script since it isn't guaranteed to be the same in each invocation.  We use this method throughout our application and performance isn't a problem - it's only this one case where we need to prefix an expression...  Thx

Comment: @user1251193 Hm,  could you perhaps try using a StringBuilder instead?  That may save a little bit of time, depending on how many concatenations you're doing.

Comment: That crossed my mind but it's only the one concatenation and the delay appears to happen within the eval rather than before it.  I think it's more of a static vs dynamic context that's causing the delay but I'll give it a try and post an update if it makes a difference.  Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

How are you measuring the time for the invocation? if possible, I would measure each part (the String building and the eval()) to determine which is taking the time, and which increases with the number of iterations. Since you say that the time increases as the number of iterations increases, look at garbage collection. The first case uses a single String -  in the later case you are building a new String each iteration, so are consuming memory. You may be running up against a heap limit.

One very useful tool for looking at this is VisualVM. http://visualvm.java.net/

Comment: Thanks Paul.  The timing is just for the eval().  This problem started out as an issue with PermGen filling up so I've been actively engaged with the profiler for a few days now (I use YourKit).  At one point I did suspect GC but due to the unloading of classes and clearing of PermGen (which is very last minute and very intensive) rather than Heap (of which I have GB's free).  I've come up with an alternate approach that also runs in ~1ms (which I will post when I get a moment) but I'm still hoping someone can explain the underlying reason for this behaviour which is still a mystery to me.

Comment: @user1251193 Could you share your complete benchmark? Depending on how it is used the fixed string could be interned and maybe Groovy eval has an optimization that only compiles the script once and then uses the cached instance for the second iteration. Whereas the concatenation forces a new String to be created. And also the Groovy and Java version would be interesting.

Comment: I'm not a liberty to share the actual code but I've more or less reproduced the problem with what I've shown above - the timing is measured via writes to the log before and after the call to eval (not sure what, if any, implications that may have).  The timing difference occurs upon the very invocation (<1ms with no concatenation vs 30+ms with it), and the timing does not improve with either method after subsequent invocations even though the engine itself is cached through many iterations (and in this case it is executing a against exactly the same string).

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately we recognized that

```
eval("['one','two','three']")
```

returns exactly that, so

```
Object test = engine.eval(first)
```

is equivalent to

```
engine.eval("test = " + "['one','two','three']") // see text above for exact syntax
Object test = engine.get("test")
```

and yet it runs in effectively no time at all.

I'm still very curious why making the pattern dynamic has such a dramatic impact on the performance of the eval() but I suspect it will take someone with a deep understanding of the Java and/or groovy runtime elements to shed any light on it.

Thanks to everyone who tried to assist.
Regards,

ps.